# fork() and exec() run in parallel in C

Tags: c

I am trying to run three execv("./test",execv_str) in parallel. And I need to print out success message when each of execv() completes successfully.

But now I get result as following:

```
username@username:~/Desktop/$./test -p
SUCCESS
SUCCESS
SUCCESS
username@username:~/Desktop/$ TESTING
TESTING
TESTING
```

The expected result will be:

```
username@username:~/Desktop/$./test -p
TESTING
SUCCESS
TESTING
SUCCESS
TESTING
SUCCESS
username@username:~/Desktop/$
```

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int fork_execv()
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    /* Handling Child Process */
    if(pid == 0){
        char* execv_str[] = {"./test", NULL};
        if (execv("./test",execv_str) < 0){
            status = -1;
            perror("ERROR\n");
        }
    }

    /* Handling Child Process Failure */
    else if(pid < 0){
        status = -1;
        perror("ERROR\n");
    }

    return status;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc == 1){
        sleep(5);
        printf("TESTING\n");
    }
    else{
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
            if (fork_execv() != -1){ 
                printf("SUCCESS\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to modify my code to make it work?

Comment: C does not support multithreading

Comment: @DeepeshChoudhary - This question doesn't involve threads.  (And note that C does, in fact, support threads.)

Comment: @ Oliver Charlesworth Really? Please tell me how(or share a link). I wanted to use that in c since a long time.

Comment: @DeepeshChoudhary - http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread

Comment: You need to investigate `wait`.

Comment: Note that you don't initialize `status` in the function, so you're not guaranteed a sane return value on success — you might get a `-1` back even if the code succeeded.

Comment: @DeepeshChoudhary if you are still interested in this in n1570 C2011 standard there is 7.26, where you can found "threads.h". Also on C you can work with posix "pthread.h"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int fork_execv()
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();

    /* Handeling Chile Process */
    if(pid == 0){
        char* execv_str[] = {"./test", NULL};
        if (execv("./test",execv_str) < 0){
            status = -1;
            perror("ERROR\n");
        }
    }

    /* Handeling Chile Process Failure */
    else if(pid < 0){
        status = -1;
        perror("ERROR\n");
    }

    return pid;
}
void handler(int sig){
    printf("SUCCESS\n");
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if (argc == 1){
        sleep(5);
        printf("TESTING\n");
    }
    else{

        int i;
        pid_t process_id;
        for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
            if ((process_id = fork_execv()) != -1){
              if(process_id != 0){
                signal(SIGCHLD, handler);
                waitpid(process_id, NULL, 0);
              }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here what I would do. After the fork, I return the pid, check if it isn't 0 (so we are in the father process) and make the father wait for the son. To print "success", I bind the SIGCHLD signal that is triggered when a child process ends. Note that this is a little overkill and put print after the waitpid would have done the job. (But I like to bind signal.)

Comment: if use waitpid(), is that still considering running in parallel? Because when I check ps -aux | grep ./test, the child processes are produced one by one and not run together in parallel.

Comment: Indeed they aren't

Comment: The fact is that if you want to control the output order, you have to make some process wait

Comment: I got it. Thanks.